# Analyse user feed using facebook graphapi 2.x

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

With FQL, it was straightforward to get insights of social engagement of a user.For example,

Number of posts made by the user
Number of likes
Number of photo    uploads 
Number of photo tags

etc…

As FB wants to go away with FQL, there is no direct  way to get the stats with new graph api endpoints, unless you get all the data and paginate one by one.Has anybody came across with same issue ? Any workaround is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't any easy way to say this, this is a data intensive query.

- Number of posts you need `/me/posts` with `read_stream` permission
- Number of likes you need `user_likes` for pages under the `/me/likes` endpoint
- Number of photos you need `/me/photos/uploaded` with `user_photos` permission

etc.

You really just need to go into the documentation and match the FQL to the Graph API equivalent.